# Gimp "Dark" theme - can't see menus with KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, themes, gimp

I installed KDE Plasma 5.18.5 on standard Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm enjoying it. However, something is badly wrong with the colors of Gimp (I've always used Gimp's Dark theme). Maybe I also have some KDE theme setting that's causing this?

The tool menu is badly colored:

[image]

But these menus are completely unusable - I can't see the values:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Change the Gimp Theme**

This appears to be a problem with Gimp's "Dark Theme" and my KDE Plasma settings. In Gimp, under **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Interface** -> **Theme**, change the theme to Gray, Light, or System. Any of these works, while Dark does not:

[image: Menus better with System Theme]

**BTW: Icon Theme**

You may also want to change the Icon Theme from Symbolic, which is very low-contrast and muddy:

[image: Symbolic gray icon theme]

Call me old school, but I like the "Legacy" icon theme, personally:

[image: Legacy icon theme is more distinct]